# Azure DevOps - how to change the deliver setting "do not deliver" for an individual user

Tags: azure-devops, tfs, notifications

We have a new user in our org that is not getting email notifications for TFS tickets. It appears that her account is set up with delivery settings "do not deliver", but I cannot seem to find where to change this.

Navigating to Collection > Admin Settings > Notifications > Subscribers, and typing in her name, I get this:
[image: User Delivery Settings]

But when I have her go to User settings > Notifications, all I see is a list of notifications she is subscribed to, each one showing her name with "do not deliver". I do not see any place to change the delivery setting.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you checked the users profile page?
Maybe she accidentally opted out?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/notifications/about-notifications?view=azure-devops#preferred-email-address

And also

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/notifications/manage-your-personal-notifications?view=azure-devops&tabs=new-account-enabled#unsubscribe-or-opt-out-of-a-team-or-out-of-box-oob-notification-subscription

Or maybe the mail address was not set up (right):
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/users-notification-settings-says-do-not-deliver-bu/856440#T-N858225

I also found an interesting topic here at stackoverflow, about `Do not deliver` and `AAD` defaults:
[Azure DevOps Deployment Approval Notifications not delivered to Azure AD Security Group members](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62525294/azure-devops-deployment-approval-notifications-not-delivered-to-azure-ad-securit)

Comment: She sent me a screen shot of her user profile page, and each subscription line has her name, with "do not deliver" below it. I don't think she changed this herself; I am starting to think it's a default setting for new users, though I don't know where to change that either.

Thanks for the links; I have read through them, but I still do not see where a user can change their delivery settings. The image I posted above even says they can be changed in the user profile page, but that doesn't seem to be an option.

Comment: Added an extra check in the answer above, never knew that having an account without a mail address was even possible

Comment: That was it! I had the user check her User Profile, and there was no email address under Preferred Email. This is a new phenomenon, the last 2 people we hired had the same issue. Thanks!!!

Comment: @Kurt nice! Maybe you can change the title to include the "how to change the deilver setting: do not deliver for an individual user" part, that was your real question in the end.

Comment: Good idea, will do!